# return Json as string from spring controller and get in Ajax to populate in datatable

Tags: jquery, json, spring

am trying to convert my list of data as string using Json and return it to Ajax to populate in datatable. The spring controller able to convert it to Json data but am confusing how to return it from spring and get it in Ajax success, can anyone help me on this. Below is my code details,

Controller Class

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/json")
    public class JsonController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/postEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody
        String postEmployeeData() throws JsonGenerationException,
                JsonMappingException, IOException {
            List<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Users user = new Users();
                user.setName("Akram");
                user.setPrincipal("DEC");
                users.add(user);
            }
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String data = mapper.writeValueAsString(users);
            return data;
        }
```

Jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    url : "/myApp/json/postEmployee.do",
                    cache : false,
                    success : function(response) {
                        display(response);
                        alert('Inside success');
                        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                        alert(obj);
                    },
                    error : function() {
                        alert('Error while request..');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

In POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here am getting no response. So please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Just return the list of users, Spring will do the conversion to JSON for you.

Comment: Is your call reaching the controller?

Comment: Thx Deinum, I tried to return the list of users but no response still. @Kiran : Yes its getting called, I checked in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a list directly if you have a properly configured Spring application it should return a json value.

```
    (...)
    public @ResponseBody List<Users> postEmployeeData() {
        (...)
        return users;
    }
```

Comment: Sry the above suggestions not did the job. @Praveen : I tried the same after u suggested but the Ajax error block is getting called before the request send to controller and response not showing any in Ajax. Please suggest me any alternate or where am doing wrong. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `ResponseEntity` to send the response back?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity List<Users> postEmployeeData() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
  List<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users> ();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Users user = new Users();
    user.setName("Akram");
    user.setPrincipal("DEC");
    users.add(user);
  }

  return ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

> Changes

**Added**

```
method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

public ResponseEntity List<Users> postEmployeeData() ...

return ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
```

**Removed**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String data = mapper.writeValueAsString(users);

return data;
```